# Finding a certain limit , binomial

Tags: limits

I thought using Newton's binomial theorem, but didn't understand where to go from there. 
$$ \
{
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\left( 1+mx \right)^n-\left( 1+nx \right)^m}{x^2}
\qquad 
}
$$
Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Use binomial theorem. You should not have any problems.

Comment: Use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{(1+mx)^n-(1+nx)^m}{x^2}=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}(mx)^k-\sum_{k=0}^{m}{m\choose k}(nx)^k}{x^2}$$
$$=\frac{[1+{n\choose 1}mx+{n\choose 2}m^2x^2+...+{n\choose n}m^nx^n]-[1+{m\choose 1}nx+{m\choose 2}n^2x^2+...+{m\choose  m}n^mx^m]}{x^2}$$
$$=\frac{(1-1)+(nmx-mnx)+\left({n\choose 2}m^2x^2-{m\choose 2}n^2x^2\right)+\left({n\choose 3}m^3x^3-{m\choose 3}n^3x^3\right)+...}{x^2}$$
$$={n\choose 2}m^2-{m\choose 2}n^2+\left({n\choose 3}m^3-{m\choose 3}n^3\right)x+...\to {n\choose 2}m^2-{m\choose 2}n^2=\frac{1}{2}mn(n-m)$$
as $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

using the rules of L'Hospital two times we get
$$\frac{1}{2}mn(n-m)$$

Comment: Is there a way of doing it without  L'Hospital's rules?
We haven't reached there yet in my course.

Comment: use the binomial Theorem, which is the hint above

Comment: I've tried it. Didn't know where to go from there :(